# Java Static method in singleton class

Tags: java, performance, static-methods

Which one is better?
I have a singleton class which is being initialised when my application starts and I have one abstract Util class. Should i create a local method in singleton class or static method in the abstract Util class? Which one is more efficient and why? Note: The method does not alter the state of the instance variables

Eclipse suggests that many of my singleton class local methods can be declared as static. Whats better in this case?

Comment: it might be better to show the code. And, better for what purpose/in which context?

Comment: Does it *read* the instance variables?

Comment: They both probably violate one or more OOP principles, particularly encapsulation.

Comment: Eclipse suggests many of the methods in my singleton class can be declared as static. I was wondering what's better?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't make this kind of decision based on performance. Any difference there is performance wise will be optimized / fixed by the compiler or JVM.

Instead, think of what's logical. Make the code make sense to an outsider. Is it the method for startup only? It should probably go in the singleton instance. Is it a more general utility thing? Put it in a utility class.

Comment: Thanks!!! Its more of utility function. I thought of it because eclipse suggests many of the functions in my Singleton class can be declared as static.

Answer (score 1):

You should build your application in such way that you don't have to care about such things in the first place. `static` methods in `abstract` make no sense. Ideally you use an I.o.C. container or, if you just want to use the singleton, propagate the instance via constructor argument or setter, as you keep your dependency graph clean.

The less classes know you use a singleton the better.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said: it depends.

As far as I understand the question, you are talking about a pure utility method (like Collections.sort). In that case, as you actually do not need an object, make it static. (In general: try to avoid useless objects which are just function collections - go for static in that case.)

If it is a function on or in dependency to a given (singleton-) object, it should go there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not intent to alter the instance variables in method, you can go with static function which is better to implement the common utils such as math functions etc. Otherwise I prefer to use singleton method over static method due to following reasons.

1. You can implement the inheritance.
2. It can be initialized lately unlike static method which will get initialized immediately once its get loaded.
3. you can free up the memory used by singleton class.
4. You can override the method.